# jquery changing page content and the hash according to a json list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm wanting to load (using ajax) assets in from external files into a container div. these are referenced in a json list of object that look like this.

```
  "pages": {
    "page1": {
      "html": "markup/page1.html",
      "css": "style/css/pages/page1.css",
      "js": "scripts/pages/page1.js"
    },
    "page2": {
      "html": "markup/page2.html",
      "css": "style/css/page2.css",
      "js": "scripts/page2.js"
    },

  }
```

Basically this is a glorified slide show that users can click next and go to the next slide/page. But I'm struggling to load each of the elements and there associated assets in as well as changing the hash using jquery.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

First, have the html include the css and js files directly, so you only need to deal with one file.

Second, you can either...

Use an iframe for the container div and load it with

```
$("#container").attr('src', url);
```

Use an ajax call to get the content, and put it in the div like so...

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            $("#container").html(html);

        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert("Failed to load page!\n" + xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);
        }
    });
```

Using the second option is better if all your css and js files are loaded up front, but if you are loading them individually and are concerned they might conflict, the iframe would be the safer way to go as I don't think changing the div HTML will unload any css or js files tht are no longer needed.